# i am trying to get some sets of numbers let's say grades from the user. the code does not work since size gets changed to a random num in the loop

Tags: arrays, c, loops, while-loop, scanf

i am trying to get some sets of numbers let's say grades from the user. the code does not work since size gets changed to a random num in the loop. I dont understand why size gets a random value after first input by the user. when I use a number instead of size everything works fine thus asking for the size of grades makes this problem.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 float average(int size, float array[size]);
 int size;
 float array[];
 float sum, avg;
 int i,j;

 int main()
 {
 printf("Hello there\n enter the number of grades you want to get average\n");
 scanf("%d",&size);
 printf("\n enter the grades\n");
 while(j<size)
 {
     scanf("%f",&array[j]);
     j++;
     printf("size and j are %d and %d\n",size,j);
  }

 return 0;
 }
```

[image]

size gets a random big value after first loop.

Comment: `float array[];` has no elements, and will only compile in a non-standard compiler (or as the last member of a `struct`).

Comment: @WeatherVane gcc assumes one element

Comment: That is non-deterministic rather than "_random_"

Comment: Cannot see why we need a screenshot of your _entire screen, and the content of interest could have been posted as _plain text_, rather than a _picture_ of plain text.

Answer (score 2):

```
float array[];
```

Gcc assumes 1 element array and `size > 1` then you will access elements outside the array. This code will only compile if compiler supports it as an extension. It is an undefined behaviour. You need to have an array which can accommodate `size` elements.

gcc emits warning:

```
<source>:7:7: warning: array 'array' assumed to have one element
    7 | float array[];
      |       ^~~~~
```

***Always read warnings***

Comment: I would go further and advise always _resolve_ the warnings. (`-Werror`)